# Toxins: Make Bombs, and...?

Tags: space-station-13

So I've recently been learning the ins and outs of Toxins, having made my first successful bomb recently (Which I failed to properly use to defend the station, of course...), and now...well, now I'm wondering if there's anything else that Toxins is really supposed to do.

It seems like its well-stocked with a variety of gasses beyond O2 and Plasma, yet I can't think of what use any of it could be beyond building more bombs.  I'm also a bit perplexed because, in one round when I was RD, the guy in Toxins was complianing to RnD that they 'weren't researching fast enough', even though near as I can tell there isn't actually anything that is affected by RnD in Toxins.

Is bomb making pretty much all you do?  Or is there some other duty I'm not realizing?  What are the uses for the other gas canisters you have in storage?  Do some servers offer different things for the Toxins department to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On /tg/ based servers, the Research/Science wing generally has several things:

Xenobiology - Breeding slimes to become one and get subsequently killed by the AI, or get some gold slimes to griff the shuttle with after it docks at centcom (there's other things you can do with Xenobio but those are the only two that people REALLY care about)

Research lab - De-construct all pieces of technology on the station to research them and make them more efficient/upgraded. Mining is an integral part of this, if you have no miners, you're likely not going to be doing much researching.

Robotics lab - Technically a part of the science wing, robotics benefits from the research lab with better, faster, more dangerous mechs. These mechs can often be given to security/medical bay/mining to make them more efficient.

Then there's genetics.

Genetics is in a weird halfway point between medical bay and research, they fall under jurisdiction of both the RD and CMO. Their job is basically two things:

1.) Clone the dead people of the station.

2.) Research superpowers via heavily irradiating monkeys.

In practice, most geneticists ignore number 1 and go straight to number 2, get hulk, telekineses, and xray vision and go play "powergamey station vigilante douche".

So in short, yeah, research does a lot more than just make bombs to blow up security with.

Comment: This is actually a question specifically about Toxins, not the Science branch in general.

Comment: Ah, my mistake, in that case - Yes. Toxins only makes bombs.